# how to bold a row in jtable based on value of a column c#, mvc, json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I am new to JTable. I have JSon data returning from controller and loading that data into JTable.
Json data has a boolean column, say 'ShowBold'; I want to bold the whole row in JTable where ShowBold is true but on the other hand I dont want to show 'ShowBold' in JTable.
I am using c#, mvc 4 and data comming in JSon format

Any guidance please.

My code is as under:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyDiv').jtable({
            title: 'Client Data',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting:true,
            actions: { listAction: '/Home/getClientData/@Model.ID' },
            fields: { ClientID: {title: 'Client ID', width: '15%' },
            ClientName: {title: 'Client Name', width: '15%'},
            Address: {title: 'Address', width: '15%'},
            AmountDue: {title: 'Amount Due', width: '15%'},
            ShowBold: {title: 'Show Bold', width: '15%'}
        });

        $('#MyDiv').jtable('reload');

    });

</script>

<div id="MyDiv">Client data here.... </div>
```

- I don't want to show 'ShowBold' in JTable
- I want to bold all rows where 'ShowBold' = true in JTable.
- My data is in JSon format.
- I am using C#, MVC, Entity framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove column ShowBold from jtable initialization, and use display function at each column level where you can style your cell.

```
 $('#MyDiv').jtable({
    title: 'Client Data',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    sorting:true,
    actions: { listAction: '/Home/getClientData/@Model.ID' },
    fields: { 
        ClientID: {
            title: 'Client ID', width: '15%',
            display: function (data) {
                if(data.record.ShowBold) 
                    return '<b>'+data.record.ClientID+'</b>'
                else
                    return data.record.ClientID;
            }
        },
        ClientName: {
            title: 'Client Name', width: '15%',
            display: function (data) {
                if(data.record.ShowBold) 
                    return '<b>'+data.record.ClientName+'</b>'
                else
                    return data.record.ClientName;
                }
        },
        Address: {
            title: 'Address', width: '15%',
            display: function (data) {
                if(data.record.ShowBold) 
                    return '<b>'+data.record.Address+'</b>'
                else
                    return data.record.Address;
             }
        },
        AmountDue: {
            title: 'Amount Due', width: '15%',
            display: function (data) {
                if(data.record.ShowBold) 
                    return '<b>'+data.record.AmountDue+'</b>'
                else
                    return data.record.AmountDue;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the [ApiReference](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-display).